# Movie where stranded people kill (but not eat) a person to survive famine

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've seen this movie between 2006 and 2007 on cable TV.

I am not sure but the protagonist could be `Robin Williams` .

In the movie, a group of people are struggling to survive famine. And they come up with the idea of choosing one victim (by random selecting device, not sure) so that the rest of them would have more food left.

This person is then killed.

I can remember one scene in which the girlfriend of the man to be killed, is collecting pieces of food to offer to him since he will shortly die.

One of the quotes they used in the trailer of this movie is :

> What will I eat tomorrow?

Again, that quote could have been said by Robin Williams.

EDIT: It is worth mentioning that when anyone is killed, he/she is killed in order for him/her not to consume any more food. No cannibalism involved throughout the movie. On a different topic: You would see people hiding food before opening the door to anyone who knocks.

I always thought: why won't they just let the guy go, and maybe starve to death on his own? Why the extra burden of having to kill him. He/she might survive alone, you just don't give any food to them.. That bugged me the whole time I watched the movie, but there might be a reason that I may have missed.

Comment: I don't think Williams was ever in a film like this. Did the film look recent? What was the production value like? And was the entire plot about cannibalism or is that just a small part of it?

Comment: The film IS recent. possibly no earlier than 1997. I am not sure what you mean by production value. The entire plot was about how these people struggle to survive famine. Now that you mentioned cannibalism, I don't think they killed people so that they can eat them. They killed them so that they won't consume food. @Walt

Comment: By production value I mean if it seemed low budget or not. *"They killed them so that they won't consume food"* Ohh, I see. Much clearer, thanks. Williams was in a [holocaust movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_the_Liar) where people starved in the ghetto, but I'm not sure this particular scenario happened there.

Comment: "Delicatessen", (1991), is pretty much ruled out by your clarification, but it's a very close match otherwise.  The story involves a landlord hiring a former clown as a handyman, with the intention of eventually killing and cooking him.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101700/

Comment: @WillFeldman No .. It is not Delicatessen. I may be wrong, but the movie I am talking about might have multiple story-lines and one of them is this one about hunger and surviving famine.

Comment: How sure are you that this was Robin Williams? 50-60 ... 90 percent sure?

Comment: @mGoLos I would say 20-30% sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Being Human](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_Human_(1994_film)) (1994)

You seem to have a few scenes mixed up, but you've given me a specific detail which I remember very clearly.

About seventy minutes into the film during the colonial timeline he has to hide his food because everyone else is starving. It happens in a tent though and it really isn't very lengthy or thematic, but the scene is unmistakably Robin Williams hiding food.